# Custom Post Type - Upload Form

Tags: custom-post-types

So Im just getting started with Custom Post Types.  I'm trying to make a custom post called a Certificate.  The thing is, I don't need any of the usual 'editor' boxes or anything that would normally be in a post.  All I need is an upload form for a user to upload a file.

So I've set up the the Certificate post-type, and I made it so it doesn't support anything, so nothing appears on the page.  I then added a 'admin_init' hook to display a form.

But now i'm a little stuck.  Can someone give me a breif outline of what hooks to use to process the form?  How do I make it so it activates this hook only for 'Certificate' post types?

Comment: have any example form code you wish to share? It'll make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45194/13486).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `save_post` hook. Your hooked-in function examines the posted data and runs a block of code only if the `$_POST['post_type']` matches your Certificate type.

The function should also ensure that the user has the authentication and intention of running the particular function.

More information including a full worked example of adding a post meta box and processing the data is included in the WordPress codex at: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box