# set a chosen image-file-input as a featured image from wp frontend

Tags: post-thumbnails, front-end

**SCENARIO** : I allow to create posts from front-end. The form also has four image upload fields. I use the code pasted below for image attachments and setting the post thumbnail.

```
//insert attachments
    if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
        $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid);
        }
        } 


 //attachment helper function   
 function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK){ return __return_false(); 
        } 
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

        $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );
        //set post thumbnail
        if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
        return $attach_id;
            }
```

The post-thumbnail/featured image that is set through this code is the **LAST** image that is uploaded. I tried a google search for "set post thumbnail from frontend wordpress" and grazed through a lot of articles but none came close to what I am asking here. Majority of threads I came across at SE in regards to front-end posting, either talks about [setting the featured image](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72406/set-featured-image-front-frontend-form) or about [multiple uploads](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45188/front-end-post-with-multiple-upload-images). I have also checked all the suggested questions which were prompted, while I was writing this question just to make sure if it has been asked before.'

If it matters, here is the html that is used in the form, pretty standard.

```
<input type="file" name="image-one" id="image-one"/>
<input type="file" name="image-two" id="image-two"/>
<input type="file" name="image-three" id="image-three"/>
```

**REQUEST** : It would be great if I could get a solution that helps to assign any chosen image-input-field as a featured-image but at this moment, at least what I need to set the **FIRST** image input to be set as a featured-image/post-thumbnail. Kindly suggest a solution.

> Bottomline here is that I do not have an issue with setting
>   post-thumbnail but question is about having a choice to choose any of
>   the uploaded images as post-thumbnail or at least the first image,
>   instead of the last image as set by the current code.

Footnote : I have just put here what came to my mind as necessary. If you want some more information, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Re: set the FIRST image input to be set as a featured-image/post-thumbnail**

Given that you know `input name="image-one"` is going to be your featured image, you can check for `image-one` as your `$file_handler` value in `function insert_attachment` after the call to `media_handle_upload`, then set the thumbnail. See the following code.

Do note that I set `image-one` as the field name to look for and pass it every time.

```
<?php
$thumbnail_field = 'image-one';
if ( ! empty( $_FILES ) ) {
    foreach ( $_FILES as $file => $array )
        $newupload = insert_attachment( $file, $pid, $thumbnail_field );
}

//attachment helper function   
function insert_attachment( $file_handler, $post_id, $set_thumb = false ) {
    if ( UPLOAD_ERR_OK !== $_FILES[ $file_handler ]['error'] )
        return false; 

    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php';

    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

    //set post thumbnail (featured)
    if ( $attach_id && $set_thumb )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id );

    return $attach_id;
}
?>
```

**Re: assign any chosen image-input-field as a featured-image**

I think this part isn't needed as you should just label the first image field as "Featured Image". It's possible the submitter doesn't want to set a featured image now.

In looking at the code above, replace line `$thumbnail_field = 'image-one';` with the following.

```
if ( ! empty( $_POST[ 'thumbnail-field' ] ) )
    $thumbnail_field = esc_html( $_POST[ 'thumbnail-field' ] );
else
    $thumbnail_field = 'image-one';
```

This references a `select` field like below. Radio's and jQuery could be used as well to format and populate.

```
<label for="thumbnail-field">
    Thumbnail field
    <select name="thumbnail-field">
        <option value="image-one">1st</option>
        <option value="image-two">2nd</option>
        <option value="image-three">3rd</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Lastly, you might also refresh your memory on [PHP's POST method uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) and check out [WordPress's coding standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards) for writing more readable code.

Comment: For those of us a little new to programming and wordpress, what is it that you're saying in the final if statement? "if $attach_id has a number and $setthumb is true == ?" ?. The value of $file_handler, if dumped, is simply Array(), correct? In other words, "if none of these is empty, move forward?" Thanks!

Comment: Opps… that `== $file_handler` shouldn't be there. The last if condition is basically, if there's an attachment `$attach_id` and I'm supposed to set a thumbnail, `$set_thumb`, then do so.